# How to use the Clear option in a calculator for clearing a particular digit in a number in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing a calculator which has a Clear button . I can clear the whole label containing the number easily but I want that it should clear digit by digit on the button click . Is this possible . How can i implement it ?

```
-(IBAction)cancelOperation
{
currentNumber = 0;
```

calculatorScreen.text = @"0.00";

```
currentOperation = 0;
}
```

Comment: what about this. is this not working?

Comment: i think you want to delete one by one digit with button pressed am i right???

Comment: @ParasJoshi exactly. Is that possible ?

Comment: yes defiantly dude just min i post code

Comment: @TheSaad I want to delete one by one each digit with button . How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    -(IBAction)cancelOperation
    {
    currentNumber = 0;
    NSString* str = calculatorScreen.text;
    calculatorScreen.text = [str substringToIndex:[string length]-1];;

    currentOperation = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you do and you delete a letter at a time. try putting this method into your button

**Edit**

*Try this*

```
-(IBAction)cancelOperation
    {
      NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:label.text];
      NSString *deleteOne;
      deleteOne = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
      label.text = deleteOne;
```

and even if you want to set your variable of type double use this

```
     currentOperation = [deleteOne doubleValue];
     }
```

**Edit2**

As I can see here, u asked for delete a label

> I can clear the whole label containing the number easily but I want that it should clear digit by digit on the button click

This however is how to reduce your number by number variable currentNumber

```
-(IBAction)cancelOperation
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentNumber];
    NSString *deleteOne;
    deleteOne = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-1];
    currentNumber = [deleteOne intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i", currentNumber);
}
```

at this point whether this method is not good even I believe that I have not understood the problem and your question

Comment: It will not work as local declaration of string hides the instance variable. As the values are in double.

Comment: Not working. It deletes the complete number again. Is there not any other method except converting it to string ?